# How to put a Glyphicon inside input tag?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying put a glyphicon inside input tag html but it's incorrect.

I mean

[image: search]    **<= Image**

**Code**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search_box pull-right"  class="form-control search_box" placeholder="Search for..."
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span> 
                            /> <!-- end input -->
```

Comment: Do you want it inside placeholder ? or like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/y6xtuj4c/1/)

Comment: @Hazard That's exact what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="right-inner-addon">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/y6xtuj4c/1/)</kbd>

[Other ways to show](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/support-glyph-and-fa-icon-inside-input)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this with your markup.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="search-query"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="search-query">
</div>
```

It would look like this

[image]

and using CSS make the span's background color transparent, like so

```
#search-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#search-icon input {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

Then finally it would look like this(what you want). You could add a placeholder too if you wish.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you are very clear with representing the second image. Your code is only showing the first image

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" class="placeicon" placeholder="&#xf002; Search">
            <button class="searchButton" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**And then add external CSS:**

```
 .placeicon {
      font-family: fontawesome;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for `input-group-addon`: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

> **Just a note**: you can't put tags inside a `input`. Have a look at: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add below this way:

```
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label class="control-label">
      <code>.inner-addon.<i>left</i>-addon</code>
    </label>
    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5D8fv5o5egpKpYz509O3?p=preview)**